# Search returned no results on specific subsite

Tags: 2013, search-results

I have a SharePoint 2013 specific subsite that returned no results when I use "Find File" search and OOB search box using normal or even site collection admin account. I will get results ONLY if I use Farm Admin account. Other subsites and site collections don't have such issue. I couldn't find any issue on ULS.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the service account for search didn't have enough access to read your end user's access.

Follow below for more:
https://troygerber.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/only-get-search-results-when-logged-into-sharepoint-as-sharepoint-farm-account/

Answer (score 0):

The file should have been added to search index, as your farm-account is able to find the file. Please check anyway to make sure: Central Administration -> Service Applications -> Search Service Application -> Crawl Log -> Klick on the number of "Successes" at the correct Content Source -> Type your filename and klick "Search". Your result should look like this and contain your file:
[image: Index Results]

I think you did not perform a successful crawl after creating the page and adding permissions to users. Click on "Crawl History" on the same page and check if you can find a successful crawl. If not, start a new incremental.